# Is it possible to remove programs from displaying on "Alt+Tab"?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I want to know if it is possible to prevent (for example) *"MS Outlook"* and *"Skype"* from exibing on *"Alt+Tab"*. Look image:

[image]

Comment: No;  This is a basic feature of Windows.

Comment: Based on some light Googling, it appears that as an end-user, nope, can't do it.  However, if you are creating a program, it seems there are ways to set properties so it won't show up.